# C++ throw dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++

What is the type of the exception object in the following thrown:

Question1> `range_error r("error"); throw r;`

Answer1>   an object of range_error

Question2> `exception *p = &r; throw *p;`

Answer2>   a sliced object of exception

Question3> `exception *p = &r; throw p;`

Answer3>   a pointer pointing to range_error is thrown. The capture-handling can access the range_error member functions through dynamic binding.

Do I get these question right?

// Updated and Compiled and Run on VS2010

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ExClassA
{
public:
    virtual void PrintMe() const
    {
        cout << "ExClassA" << endl;
    }
};

class ExClassB : public ExClassA
{
public:
    virtual void PrintMe() const
    {
        cout << "ExClassB" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    ExClassB exClassB;
    ExClassA *p = &exClassB;

    try
    {
        throw *p;
    }
    catch (const ExClassA& e)
    {
        e.PrintMe();        
    }

    try
    {
        throw p;
    }
    catch (const ExClassA* e)
    {
        e->PrintMe();
    }
}
```

The first try-catch of above program prints "ExClassA"

The second try-catch of above program prints "ExClassB"

Comment: Reference: Lippman 17.1.

Comment: It depends what you have in mind when you say "new".

Comment: @Kerrek, I have thought about that 'new' may introduce confusion and I have removed it from the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are right in all three. The type of the thrown object (IIRC) is the static type of the object being thrown. I would have to dig into the standard for a while to find the exact quotes, but a simple example seems to confirm this:

```
struct base {};
struct derived : base {};
void t() {
    derived d;
    base * b = &d;
    throw *b;
}
int main() {
    try {
        t();
    } catch ( derived const & ) {
        std::cout << "derived" << std::endl;
    } catch ( base const & ) {
        std::cout << "base" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If the dynamic type of the object being thrown was used, then `*b` would have type `derived` and the first `catch` would succeed, but empirically the second `catch` is executed (g++).

In the last case, the object thrown is a pointer to `exception` that refers to a `range_error` object. The slight difference is again what can be caught, the compiler will not catch in a `catch (range_error*)` block. The answer is correct, but I would have specified the type of the pointer, as much as the type of the pointee. (The type of the pointer is somehow implicit in the answer)

Comment: The relevant standardese is in §15.1/3.

Comment: @David, is it true that default modifier of struct inheritance is PUBLIC?

Comment: @q0987: The only difference between a `class` and a `struct` is that the default access specifier for `class` is `private`, while for `struct` is public. That is for both inheritance and member access.

Answer (score 6):

Throwing an object always results in the thrown object being a *copy* of the object you threw, based on the static type of that object. Thus your first two answers are correct.

The third one is a little more complicated. If you `catch(range_error*)` you won't catch the exception because the types don't match. If you `catch(exception*)` you won't be able to access members of `range_error` in the caught pointer; you can `dynamic_cast` that pointer back to a range_error pointer though.

Comment: Also, throwing pointers to local variables is bad.  RAII will cleanup that var and the pointer will be DEAD

Comment: @Bob, good point hadn't thought about that. Is a caught exception a local variable in the usual sense, or is it special somehow?

Comment: This only arises with throwing pointers, you just have to make sure the pointer is to something valid.  When you throw something by value (not a pointer) than it will copy it to wherever it goes.  So a caught exception is a local variable which is a copy of the thrown exception.

Comment: @Mark, can you check my update2 where the second try-catch prints what I expected but NOT what you said.

Comment: @q0987, you're calling a virtual function on a `ClassA` pointer, so it works the same as any other polymorphic pointer. What I meant in my answer is that you couldn't access any non-virtual functions or data members of `ClassB` in the object.

Answer (score 3):

All three answers are correct.  Just note that you'll have to catch a
pointer type in the third case.

The usual way to throw an exception is:

```
throw range_error("error");
```

At the throw site, you normally know the exact type of exception you 
want to throw.  About the only exception I can think of is when the
exception was passed in as an argument, e.g.:

```
void f( std::exception const& whatToDoInCaseOfError )
{
    //  ...
    throw whatToDoInCaseOfError;  //  slices
}
```

It's not a frequence case, but if you want to support it, you'll need a
separate exception hierarchy of your own, with a virtual `raise`
function:

```
class MyExceptions
{
public:
    virtual ~MyExceptions() {}
    virtual void raise() const = 0;
};

template<typename ExceptionType>
class ConcreteException : public ExceptionType, public MyExceptions
{
public:
    virtual void raise() const
    {
        throw *this;
    }
};
```

The client code then wraps the exception he wants to be thrown in a
`ConcreteException`, and you call the `raise` function on it, rather
than invoke `throw` directly.

Comment: we can simply replace the code from "throw whatToDoInCaseOfError;" to "throw" to avoid the slice issue. If I remember it right, rethrow in this way doesn't introduce slice issue.

Comment: @q0987 But we can't rethrow unless we're in a catch block somewhere, in which case, the client doesn't have to pass in the exception.