# C++ -- Why 'what' print "Unknown exception" in catch scope?

Tags: c++

```
try
{
    range_error r("Hi I am hereeeee!");
    cout << r.what() << endl;   // print "Hi I am hereeeee!"  // case one
    exception *p2 = &r; 
    cout << p2->what() << endl; // print "Hi I am hereeeee!"  // case two
    throw p2;
}
catch (exception *e)
{
    cout << e->what() << endl;  // print "Unknown exception"  // case three
}
```

Question>

I don't know why case three prints "Unknown exception" instead of "Hi I am hereeeee!"?
The printed result is copied from VS2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This program results in undefined behavior.  Because the variable `r` is declared *inside* the `try` block, it goes out of scope before the catch handler is invoked.  At this point, `e` points to some area on the stack where an object of type `range_error` *used to* exist.

The following program should print the expected results:

```
range_error r("Hi I am hereeeee!");
try
{
    cout << r.what() << endl;   // print "Hi I am hereeeee!"  // case one
    exception *p2 = &r; 
    cout << p2->what() << endl; // print "Hi I am hereeeee!"  // case two
    throw p2;
}
catch (exception *e)
{
    cout << e->what() << endl;  // print "Hi I am hereeeee!"  // case three
}
```

However, you should not throw a pointer to an object, you should throw the object itself.  The run-time library will store a copy of the `range_error` object and pass that copy to the exception handler.

Thus, you should use the following code instead:

```
try
{
    range_error r("Hi I am hereeeee!");
    cout << r.what() << endl;   // print "Hi I am hereeeee!"  // case one
    throw r;
}
catch (const exception& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;  // print "Hi I am hereeeee!"  // case two
}
```

Comment: I should haven identified this problem myself. Thank you

Comment: Jeez, you **must** have copied me, except your answer is better.

Comment: @John: Except, I also posted first, and fixed the comment in the `catch` block ;-)

Comment: Apart from throwing by value, the generally used approach is to [catch by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023032/catch-exception-by-pointer-in-c/2023045#2023045). The code in the answer is already like that, but I think it deserves an explicit remark.

Comment: @ncases: indeed.  However, the OP's been asking several questions about exception handling and seems well aware of [slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014626/c-throw-dereferenced-pointer) objects in exception handlers.

Answer (score 3):

Because by the time you get to the `catch`, your `range_error` has been destroyed and you're catching a dangling pointer. Either move the `range_error` declaration outside the `try` block or, better yet, throw an instance and catch by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Because the pointed to exception object has gone out of scope by the time you catch the exception. If you wrote

```
range_error r("Hi I am hereeeee!");
try
{
    cout << r.what() << endl;   // print "Hi I am hereeeee!"  // case one
    exception *p2 = &r; 
    cout << p2->what() << endl; // print "Hi I am hereeeee!"  // case two
    throw p2;
}
catch (exception *e)
{
    cout << e->what() << endl;  // print "Unknown exception"  // case three
}
```

it would print what you expected.